# Undeclared FTDI Identifiers

Tags: c++, ftdi

I'm trying out basic FTDI coding, and here is a simple program that should be able to read bytes from a single FTDI device:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ftd2xx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int scan_and_read()
{
    unsigned long int ftDevCount = 0;
    FT_STATUS ftStatus;
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *devInfo;
    DWORD numDevs;
    DWORD EventDWord;
    DWORD TxBytes;
    DWORD RxBytes;
    DWORD BytesReceived;
    char RxBuffer[256];


    // 
    // horrible assumption: there will only be one device connected
    // or, the very least, the first device to be connected will be the desired device
    // 
    ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numDevs);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
        cout << "Devices connected: " << numDevs << endl;
    }
    else {
        // FT_CreateDeviceInfoList failed 
        return 1;
    }

    devInfo =
        (FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE)*numDevs);
    ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfoList(devInfo, &numDevs);
    string serial_info = devInfo[0].SerialNumber;


    ftStatus = FT_OpenEx((PVOID)serial_info.c_str(), FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER, &ftHandle);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
        cout << "Device opened" << endl;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }

    FT_GetStatus(ftHandle, &RxBytes, &TxBytes, &EventDWord);
    if (RxBytes > 0) {
        ftStatus = FT_Read(ftHandle, RxBuffer, RxBytes, &BytesReceived);
        if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
            for (int i = 0; i < RxBytes; i++)
            {
                cout << "Byte " << i << ": " << *(&(BytesReceived)+i) << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    FT_Close(ftHandle);

    cout << "All data read." << endl;

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    cout << scan_and_read() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studios says that all of the identifiers (other than the unsigned long int) used to declare the variables are undeclared:

> c:\users\histo\source\repos\ftdi_intro\ftdi_intro\ftdiintro.cpp(17): error C2065: 'FT_STATUS': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\histo\source\repos\ftdi_intro\ftdi_intro\ftdiintro.cpp(17): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'ftStatus'
>   1>c:\users\histo\source\repos\ftdi_intro\ftdi_intro\ftdiintro.cpp(17): error C2065: 'ftStatus': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\histo\source\repos\ftdi_intro\ftdi_intro\ftdiintro.cpp(18): error C2065: 'FT_HANDLE': undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\histo\source\repos\ftdi_intro\ftdi_intro\ftdiintro.cpp(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'ftHandle'
>   1>c:\users\histo\source\repos\ftdi_intro\ftdi_intro\ftdiintro.cpp(18): error C2065: 'ftHandle': undeclared identifier

... etc.

I can't find anything syntactically wrong with my code or the header file included; what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Visual Studio cannot find your libraries. You can add them (VS 2017) at Project>Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories.

Remember to provide dlls as well in Project>Properties>Linker>Additional Library Directories to get the compiled program running.